# How to use IN clause in iot hub route query

Tags: azure-iot-hub

The following query is not working in route query:
$body.Weather.Temperature in ['30','50']

[image]

I checked the documentation and the syntax looks right.

Comment: the Temperature is a numeric type, so the correct query string should be $body.Weather.Temperature IN [30, 50] but after this change, the Syntax error is still generated during the Save process. It looks like this is either a bug or it is not supported in the routes query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IN** and **NIN** (not in) operator it used to check the item is or isn't in the array constants like `['wired', 'wifi']`.

For your case, you need use Comparison operator: `>=` and `<=` like this:

`$body.Weather.Temperature >= 30 AND $body.Weather.Temperature <= 50`

For detailed information you can reference ["IoT Hub query language for device twins, jobs, and message routing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#get-started-with-device-to-cloud-message-routes-query-expressions).

**Update:**

For selecting the exact value 30/50 you can use the following query string as a workaround.

`$body.Weather.Temperature = 30 OR $body.Weather.Temperature = 50`

Comment: My intention is use the exact value, in that case i wanted to filter just temperatures 30 and 50. As @roman-kiss commented above, event if the temperature were a string value it caused syntax error.

Comment: @Henrique Sorry for my misunderstanding, I can reproduce your issue. I update my answer by adding a workaround you can check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this worked correctly, altough I didn't like the structure, IN clause should work in route queries too. I gonna find a way to report it to microsoft just to update the iot hub query language documentation.

Comment: @Henrique You can give a feedback at the bottom of [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#next-steps) after signed in or via Azure Portal top button :).

Comment: @Henrique I get confirmation of this issue. The IN operator is supported for device twin query but not supported for routing query. From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#device-and-module-twin-queries), you can see the IN operator is under “Device twin queries” section.