# How to add multiple conditions in IoT hub Routes - Query string

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

When implementing the custom routing of Azure IoT Hub, I tried to add multiple conditions in **query string** option from Azure IoT hub Custom Endpoint like below.

```
level IN ['critical','warning','info']
```

But if I add the above condition the Azure Portal throws an error on the syntax.
If I replace the above condition with **level = 'critical'**, it's working as expected for Device To Cloud Messages. 
[image]

But, My intention is, When the level property has any one of this 3 values("critical","warning","info"), then I want to redirect the Device to Cloud Message to custom routing endpoints.

Please correct me what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692936/how-to-use-in-clause-in-iot-hub-route-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use OR:

```
level = "critical" OR level = "warning" OR level = "info"
```

For details of the supported query syntax, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language#expressions-and-conditions